# for loop in bash command

Tags: bash, for-loop, pv

Hi I have a server with an old version of LXD on it which dosen't have the automated delete snapshots on it, so i created the following bash line to bulk delete but would like to add "pv" to it for a progress bar how can I put the following in a loop so pv can show me how many it has deleted of how many that match the pattern?

```
lxc info wiki | awk '{print$1}' | grep wiki | grep --null '2022' | xargs -n 1 -I{} lxc delete wiki/{}
```

I add PV at various points passing it to pv but only shows how long it takes to bring up the grep wiki. and doesn't proceed to make a progress bar for all of them listed in the to delete pile.

**Edit**

from the comments below here is what I am looking at,
the following is an output from having got rid of most of the snapshots I needed to. Ideally I would want to get rid of snapshots by date, but it doesn't recognise the dates as a date

```
Name: wiki
Remote: unix://
Architecture: x86_64
Created: 2018
Status: Running
Type: persistent
Profiles: macvlan-default
Pid: 3170
Ips:
  eth0: inet    X
  eth0: inet6   X
  eth0: inet6   X
  lo:   inet    127.0.0.1
  lo:   inet6   ::1
Resources:
  Processes: 60
  CPU usage:
    CPU usage (in seconds): 3891
  Memory usage:
    Memory (current): 231.60MB
    Memory (peak): 893.12MB
  Network usage:
    eth0:
      Bytes received: 145.47MB
      Bytes sent: 116.42MB
      Packets received: 287345
      Packets sent: 61107
    lo:
      Bytes received: 127.05kB
      Bytes sent: 127.05kB
      Packets received: 1259
      Packets sent: 1259
Snapshots:
  wiki+28092019 (taken at 2019/09/28 14:22 UTC) (stateless)
  wiki118012023 (taken at 2023/01/18 05:37 UTC) (stateless)
  wiki119082023 (taken at 2023/08/19 02:39 UTC) (stateless)
  wiki123092023 (taken at 2023/09/23 10:21 UTC) (stateless)
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, **Complete**, and **Verifiable** example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't know pv, but if you need it in a loop, I would remove the `xargs`, which IMO (due to the `-n 1`) is not very helpful anyway, but just loop explicitly over the result of `grep`.

Comment: Aside: 1) `awk '{print$1}' | grep wiki` = `awk '$1 ~ /wiki/{print $1}'`. 2) `grep --null` prints a NUL char between the file name and file content if it's printing file names but you're using it on piped input so there is no file name and so `--null` is doing nothing (probably thankfully as YMMV with what `xargs` would do with NULs in the input). 3) Given that, your `awk | grep | grep` pipeline can be reduced to just 1 command, `awk '$1 ~ /wiki/ && $1 ~ /2022/{print $1}'` which could probably be made more robust and briefer if you showed us what the input to it looked like.

Answer (score 3):

## Why is `pv` not showing progress?

There are two problems here:

### 1. Real progress bars are impossible when reading from pipes

When `pv` reads its input from a pipe, it does not know what 100% means, because it sees the end of the stream only when reaching it. Therefore, it can only show a status, not a real progress bar.

### 2. Buffering

`pv` updates the status only while its standard input is open. With `sleep 5 | pv | cat` we get an output like `0.00 B 0:00:05 [0.00 B/s] [<=>  ]` where the time part updates every second (`00:00` -> `00:01` -> ... -> `00:05`) , even though we don't read anything.
When we close its stdin after two seconds `(sleep 2; exec >/dev/null; sleep 3;) | pv | cat` we only get updates till `00:02`. After that, `pv` does not update the status anymore.

#### Why is stdin closed in your case?

Pipes are buffered. In a pipeline `fast-generate | slow-consume` the command on the left can exit before the command on the right, because it can write all its output to the buffer without waiting for it to be actually read.
Only when the buffer between those commands is full, `fast-generate` has to wait for `slow-consume` to read something from the buffer, which frees up space for writing again.

Buffers are usually big, (e.g. 64kB, see [How big is the pipe buffer?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/757307/187122)) and your input is small (a few snapshot names, only 14B each); small enough to allow it to be stored completely in `xargs`' input buffer.
`pv` forwards its input as fast as it can. Once it forwarded (and therefore read) everything, its stdin is closed.

### Attempt to fix above issues

Let's try to fix above problems by using a temporary file.

*Here, I also simplified the extraction of snapshot names using [this suggestion](https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/list-snapshots-only/12793/6). The API call is [documented here](https://github.com/canonical/lxd/blob/8a78b655ba2dc9e5fa72deb8b6b101baa53b9c8f/doc/rest-api.yaml#L9481C27-L9481C27) and [here](https://dl.stgraber.org/swag-lxd/#/instances/instance_snapshots_get). I couldn't test it myself. Please verify this step.*

```
instance=wiki
year=2022
lxc query "/1.0/instances/$instance/snapshots" |
jq -r --arg year "$year" '.metadata[] | select(endswith($year)) | sub(".*/"; "")' > old
pv old | xargs -n1 -I{} lxc delete "$instance/{}"
```

This causes another problem:

## Why is `pv` showing 100% immediately

`pv` only knows what it forwarded to `xargs`' input buffer, but it cannot inspect how much of that buffer was actually read by `xargs` so far.
When the input is shorter than the buffer size (very likely in this case, see notes on buffer size above) then `pv` immediately writes everything to `xargs` input buffer. From the perspective of `pv`, this means *it* processed 100% of the input, even though `xargs` didn't even start reading that input from its buffer.

Minimal example: `seq 9 > f; pv f | xargs -n1 bash -c 'echo "$0"; sleep 1'`

### Unbuffering doesn't seem to work here

I assumed, those issues were solvable by disabling buffering. But I had no luck with `stdbuf`, `unbuffer`, and `script`. `man unbuffer` even documents ...

> `unbuffer -p` may appear to work incorrectly if a process feeding input to unbuffer exits.
> Consider: `process1 | unbuffer -p process2 | process3`
> If process1 exits, process2 may not yet have finished.
> It is impossible for unbuffer to know [how] long to wait for `process2` and `process2` may not ever finish, for example, if it is a filter.
> For expediency, unbuffer simply exits when it encounters an EOF from either its input or `process2`.
> In  order  to  have a version of unbuffer that worked in all situations, **an oracle would be necessary**.

### Workaround: Manually notify `pv` of progress made

Instead of running `pv | xargs` we run `xargs | pv` by printing special output for `pv` only.

```
xargs -a old -I{} bash -c '
  lxc delete "$0"
  echo "$0" >&3 # inform pv that we processed another item
' "$instance/{}" 3> >(pv -l -s "$(wc -l <old)" >/dev/null)
```

This has the additional benefit of counting lines instead of bytes, making it accurate even if the snapshot names differ in length.

The extra file descriptor `>&3`/`3>` is only needed when `lxc delete` might produce output.
If it doesn't write anything to stdout, you can simplify the command to

```
xargs -a old -I{} bash -c 'lxc delete "$0"; echo "$0"' "$instance/{}" |
pv -l -s "$(wc -l <old)" >/dev/null
```

---

## Alternative to `pv` in this scenario

Wow... what a mess! I assume `pv` isn't made for inputs smaller than one buffer size. If you want a simple alternative, try GNU parallel instead of `pv | xargs`:

```
cat old | parallel --progress -j1 --bar "lxc delete $instance/{}"
```

*`cat old`* is just a placeholder for the command that extracts the snapshot names. No need to create a helper file here.

General note (may be counterproductive in your use-case): If you want, you can leave out the `-j1` and `parallel` will execute multiple commands in parallel (depending on the number of available CPU cores).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the `pv` aspect of your initial question was about but from your recent edit it sounds like all you really want to do is print the first field for every `wiki...` line between 2 dates, e.g.:

```
$ cat file | awk -v beg='2023/01/10' -v end='2023/08/25' '($1 ~ /^wiki[^[:alpha:]]+$/) && (beg <= $4) && ($4 <= end) {print $1}'
wiki118012023
wiki119082023
```

Replace `cat file` with `lxc info wiki`.